# Converting string format from 9:00:00 (H:MM:SS) to 9:00 (H:MM) in XSL1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Having some trouble with a time format change in XSL 1.0.

I have a time:
**9:00:00 (HH:MM:SS)**

but want it to display as: 
**9:00 (HH:MM)**

Not sure if it makes a difference, but the field is stored as a STRING on my tables so I think I need to trim the last three characters, '**:00**'

Any help is appreciated

Code so far:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
      xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">


<xsl:for-each select="...">
    <xsl:value-of select="Prop[@prop_name = 'time']/@val" /><br />
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the string is actually "9:00:00" and the HH:MM:SS is just a label you added to the question, possibly the simplest solution would do use substring

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($time, 1, string-length($time) - 3)" />
```

Where `$time` is a variable containing "9:00".

Alternatively, you could try and get the substring before the second `:` character, which could be done like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($time, ':'), ':', substring-before(substring-after($time, ':'), ':'))" />
```

The latter would work in the case the string is literally "9:00:00 (HH:MM:SS)" though.

To apply this to your stylesheet, just replace this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="Prop[@prop_name = 'time']/@val" /><br />
```

With this...

```
<xsl:variable name="time" select="Prop[@prop_name = 'time']/@val" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring($time, 1, string-length($time) - 3)" />
<br />
```

Comment: Thank you Tim C for taking the time to reply.  Currently have:
<br/><br/>
`<xsl:value-of select="Prop[@prop_name = 'time']/@val" /><br />`
<br/><br/>
does the below  look correct?
`<xsl:value-of select="substring(Prop[@prop_name = 'time']/@val, 1, string-length($time) - 3)" /><br />`

Comment: I've amended my answer to show how you can adapt my answer to your XSLT.

Comment: Thank you Tim C. I will test and report back.  Appreciate the time!